# My chart does not load when I run my application in iOS swift

Tags: swift, charts, uiviewcontroller

For the second page of my application I need to build a chart. My second page contains a spot for user input and entering date and time settings as well. Upon running my code this is the error I get: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7fff1c472a34)
on this line:         self.lineChartView.data = data

This is after building. How do I set the data for the chart?

@IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.finalEmail = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "username") as? String ?? ""
    self.finalPassword = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "password") as?  String ?? ""

    threshold.delegate = self


    setChartValues()

}


func setChartValues(_ count : Int = 20) {
    let values = (0..<count).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
        let val = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)) + 3)
        return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val)
    }

    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(values: values, label: "DataSet 1")
    let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set1)

    self.lineChartView.data = data

}
```

It builds without errors but when I run it says: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7fff1ad91d44)

Comment: Can you print `self.lineChartView` without a problem?

Comment: No I can't. I get a similar error.

Comment: In `storyboard/xib`, did you connect `lineChartView` outlet to its `view`?

Comment: Yeah. I just control click view and connect to the button right? They are connected.

Comment: Dual check  your lineChartView connection from storyboard to code because this error says you # I cannot access this element!  # Remove it completely from storyboard and code then try to run your app if you're code  worked that's mean your linechartview implementation is wrong.